# Efficient Erlang Port Driver

Tags: c, erlang, system, distributed

I want to spawn Erlang processes that will communicate with a C program through a Port Driver.

As spawning many of these processes can be inefficient, can I spawn one Erlang process that receives messages and queue these messages for processing with the C Program?

As this C program starts to wait for incoming jobs, will it block?

What's the best strategy/architecture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, generally you have one process which is *connected* to the port which traffic goes through. For a reasonable description of ports and how to use them read the Erlang [*Interoperability Tutorial User's Guide*](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/users_guide.html). It explains the different types of ports and their properties.

Generally speaking the documentation at http://www.erlang.org is quite good and well worth reading.